# MS Access Vb How to build a text string to reference a dynamic column in and Vb SQL query and then execute that text string using the Eval function

Tags: ms-access, vba

In the following example where POOPTrst is a a DAO recordset (systems object) referencing the Vb SQL query or statement.  this code returns "Run-time error 2482" and/or "Microsoft Access cannot find the name 'POOPTrst' you entered in the expression"  (note:  the POOPTVal variable holds a date).

```
POOPTWkDmd = Eval("POOPTrst" & "!" & POOPTVal)
```

In the following example where POOPTrst is a a DAO recordset referencing the Vb SQL query.  this code returns "Run-time error 3256" and/or "Item not found in this collection"  (note: with or without parenthesis around the variable POOPTVal)

```
POOPTWkDmd(POOPTCounterInt) = POOPTrst!Eval(POOPTVal)
```

If I remove the Eval function and the POOPT date variable and type literal characters into the code I get the proper/expected return value and/or response (note:  the problem is that 1/5/2009 is a dynamic value that is calculated at run time

```
POOPTWkDmd(POOPTCounterInt) = POOPTrst![1/5/2009]
```

Comment: Exactly what is the IDE you are using to write the code?

Comment: ??? MS Access Vb Module Environment

Comment: Then it is not MySql and it is not VB.NET.  The tags include descriptions and instructions when to use and when not too

Comment: My error... I'm new to stackoverflow and I think these were the default tags

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax: `rs("Fieldname")` instead of `rs!Fieldname`

```
POOPTVal = "1/5/2009"
POOPTWkDmd = POOPTrst(POOPTVal)
```

for more explanation see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969410/3820271

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that `Eval()` doesn't know anything about VBA variables or objects such as recordsets.  If you want to use those, build a string containing their *values* and give `Eval()` that string.

However, I'm not sure `Eval()` is what you should use here.  It seems you want to reference the value of a field in your `POOPTrst` recordset, with a variable to hold that field name.  If that is correct, use the variable with the recordset's `Fields` collection: `POOPTrst.Fields(POOPTVal).Value`