# MS Access 2013 copy a specific number of fields and paste into a new record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have found similar answers to this question, even on this site, however, the syntax has not worked for my database and I'm not sure what needs to be done. This data base is used to house audits for staff performance and accuracy. I am now in the midst of creating the forms and getting them to flow properly for the user.

When conducting an audit, the user will need to enter six specific fields into the first form. Those forms are Audit, Month, Year, Username, Location, Reviewer, and Date. The user will need to complete multiple audits, however, these six fields will always be the same.

I would like to copy these fields in the first form and carry them into the second form so the user does not have to repeat the information. Here is my current code (set to run on the click of a command button on the bottom of screen 1):

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [tblTripMem] (Audit, Month, Year, Username, Location, Reviewer, Date)"
strSQL = strSQL & " Values (" & Me.cboFP1Audit & "," & Me.Month & "," & Me.Year & "," & Me.Username & "," & Me.Location & "," & Me.Reviewer & "," & Me.Date & ") FROM [FPScreen1]"
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (currentrecord = " & Me.CurrentRecord & ")"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
```

Each time I run this I receive the following error: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

I am new to Access and am unsure of what this means or how to fix it. All I know is that I'm not finding a solution. Can anyone help? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So you want to copy data entered in fields on 1 form to a different form, is that correct? If both forms are open at the same time it's quite easy to do that without the need for sql or changing data in tables. Let me know if this is what you're trying to do and I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, except I will need to close the first form after the data is copied to the second form. Much of the time the data will need to be copied to three or four more records.

Comment: It would be better to have the code both open and close that initial form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [mock-up Access file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZicHBuWWVaUDl0QnM/view?usp=sharing) illustrating a way to do what you're doing without using SQL:

With **Form 1** open...

[image]

...complete the various fields:

[image]

Click the *Copy to Form 2* button and this will open **Form 2** and populate its fields with the data from **Form 1**:

[image]

Here's the VBA code on the *Copy to Form 2* button's OnClick event:

```vb
Private Sub cmdCopyToFrm2_Click()

    Dim frm As Form

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"

    Set frm = Forms!Form2

    With frm

        !AuditRef = Me.cboFP1Audit
        !AuditMonth = Me.txtAuditMonth
        !AuditYear = Me.txtAuditYear
        !AuditUsername = Me.txtAuditUsername
        !Location = Me.txtLocation
        !Reviewer = Me.txtReviewer
        !AuditDate = Me.txtAuditDate

    End With

End Sub
```

Note that when **Form 2** opens, the textbox that the cursor defaults to might not seem to show any data; if you move away from that textbox it should magically show (don't know why it does this, but there you go).

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...)` cannot have a FROM or WHERE clause. You insert a single record with fixed values, not data from another table.

But once you delete these clauses, you will have other errors, because you need to format your string and date values correctly to get the INSERT query to work.

And then you will still be prone to SQL injection errors. It is safer to use `Recordset.AddNew` and `.Update` to add records.

See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969410/3820271
(but without the loop)