# Need help to amend : Access SQL Statement to loop through fields in a subform

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hope this makes sense. I have adapted a code to allow me to create a report entry form for invoices.

Original code : http://windowssecrets.com/forums/sho...cess-2000-SR-1)

I have a subform (created from tbl_RepeatTemp) with a single field:
ScheduleDate

for every row entered in this subform a row should be entered in the main table. This is the code that is currently working :

```vb
Private Sub btn_CreateInvoices_Click()
'------------------------------------------------------------
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim RecordIDValue As Long
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("tbl_RepeatTemp")
Set rst = tdf.OpenRecordset

'Find the next RecordID to use
RecordIDValue = DMax("[RecordID]", "[tbl_MainData]") + 1
RowIDValue = DMax("[RowID]", "[tbl_MainData]")
UpdateCount = 0
If Me.FormProformaStatus = "" Then myStatus = "" Else myStatus = "Scheduled to Raise"

' Loop through the acheduled dates entered
Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each fld In rst.Fields
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'Insert fields in to tbl_MainData
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            StrSQL = ""
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " INSERT INTO tbl_MainData"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " (RecordID, ScheduledDate, InvoiceID, ProformaID, TransactionType, InputBy, InputDate, ProjectCode, ServiceCode, InvoiceValue, RPIIncrease, Terms, Status, InvFreq)"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " VALUES"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " (" & RecordIDValue & ", #" & Format(fld.Value, "Medium Date") & "#, '" & Me.FormInvoiceID & "', '" & Me.FormProformaID & "', 'Invoice', '" & Me.FormInputBy & "', #" & Format(Me.InputDate, "Medium Date") & "#, '" & Me.FormProjectCode & "', '" & Me.FormProductCode & "', " & Me.FormInvoiceValue & ", '" & Me.RPIIncrease & "', '" & Me.FormTerms & "','" & myStatus & "', '" & Me.FormInvFreq & "')"
            Debug.Print StrSQL          'Print values to immediate window for debugging
            CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL    'Execute SQL

            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'Insert fields into tbl_DebtTracker
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'UpdateRow ID to match tbl_MainData
            RowIDValue = RowIDValue + 1
            StrSQL = ""
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " INSERT INTO tbl_DebtTracker"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " (RowID,RecordID, ProjectCode, InvoiceID)"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " VALUES"
            StrSQL = StrSQL & " (" & RowIDValue & ", " & RecordIDValue & ", '" & Me.FormProjectCode & "', '" & Me.FormInvoiceID & "');"
            Debug.Print StrSQL          'Print values to immediate window for debugging
            CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL    'Execute SQL
            UpdateCount = UpdateCount + 1
        Next fld
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close

MsgBox UpdateCount & " Records successfully created.", , "Success !"

Set rst = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

I now want to add 2 further fields to the tbl_Repeat temp table

RPIIncrease replacing Me.RPIIncrease
RPIDate as a new field

From what I can see the variable fld worked when there was one field - which is why the ScheduledDate is fld.value - how can I add these other 2 fields ? I attach an image of my subform which might help to visualise what I am doing

[image: Mainform containing subform]

Comment: *for every row entered in this subform a row should be entered in the main table*...please explain this need as your form absolutely counters it. Main forms to sub forms (e.g., Invoices to InvoiceItems) share the one-to-many link not other way around.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. My logic is that in the subform several "Schedule Dates" can be added ie. 01/04/2016, 01/05/2016 etc... and for every date that is entered a new record is entered to tbl_maindata. It's a way to add repeating invoices without having to retype all the standard information project/value/terms etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the nested loop on the fields in `rst` will make it hard to build up your SQL string effectively. I'd recommend just writing the whole loop like this instead (remove the `fld` loop and explicitly reference each field in your `rst` recordset):

```vb
Do Until rst.EOF

    StrSQL = ""
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " INSERT INTO tbl_MainData"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " (RecordID, ScheduledDate, myNewField1, myNewField2, InvoiceID, ProformaID, TransactionType, InputBy, InputDate, ProjectCode, ServiceCode, InvoiceValue, RPIIncrease, Terms, Status, InvFreq)"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " VALUES"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " (" & RecordIDValue & ", #" & rst![Schedule Date] & "#, '" & rst!myNewField1 & "', '" & rst!myNewField2 & "', '" & Me.FormInvoiceID & "', '" & Me.FormProformaID & "', 'Invoice', '" & Me.FormInputBy & "', #" & Format(Me.InputDate, "Medium Date") & "#, '" & Me.FormProjectCode & "', '" & Me.FormProductCode & "', " & Me.FormInvoiceValue & ", '" & Me.RPIIncrease & "', '" & Me.FormTerms & "','" & myStatus & "', '" & Me.FormInvFreq & "')"
    Debug.Print StrSQL          
    CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL    

    RowIDValue = RowIDValue + 1
    StrSQL = ""
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " INSERT INTO tbl_DebtTracker"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " (RowID,RecordID, ProjectCode, InvoiceID)"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " VALUES"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & " (" & RowIDValue & ", " & RecordIDValue & ", '" & Me.FormProjectCode & "', '" & Me.FormInvoiceID & "');"
    Debug.Print StrSQL          
    CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL    
    UpdateCount = UpdateCount + 1

    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

To make this work with 2 new fields, you obviously need to add them to both your **tbl_MainData** and **tbl_RepeatTemp** tables first.

Comment: @CatParky: Yes, the `rst.Fields` loop makes no sense here. In addition to this, you need to check for SQL injection, be it deliberate or accidental. i.e. escape single quotes in input values. Or use a safe DAO approach with `Recordset.AddNew`, -> [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34969410/3820271)

Comment: Either `Recordset.AddNew` or a executing parameter query could avoid delimiter (quotes and `#`) issues.